# Meteor deploy with MUP, my collections are not deployed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, deployment, collections, meteor

I create my app with meteor and deployed it in my own server with MUP. The
deployment was successful but the database did not have my collections.

I defined the collection in the file `lib/collections/name_collection.js`. This is an example of the files:

```js
campaigns = new Mongo.Collection("campaigns");
campaigns.initEasySearch(['name','startDate','endDate']);

campaigns.newSchema=function(){
    return new SimpleSchema({
        name:{
            type: String,
            label: 'Nome'
        },
        startDate:{
            type: 'datetime',
            label: 'Data inizio'
        },
        endDate:{
            type: 'datetime',
            label: 'Data fine'
        }
    });
};
campaigns.editSchema=function(){
    return new SimpleSchema({
        c_id:{
            type: String,
            label: 'id'
        },
        editName:{
            type: String,
            label: 'Nome'
        },
        editStartDate:{
            type: 'datetime',
            label: 'Data inizio'
        },
        editEndDate:{
            type: 'datetime',
            label: 'Data fine'
        }
    });
};

SimpleSchema.messages({
    "required name": "Il [label] è richiesto",
    "required startDate": "La [label] è richiesto",
    "required endDate": "La [label] è richiesto"
});

campaigns.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
        // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
        return (userId && doc.user === userId);
    },
    update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
        // can only change your own documents
        return doc.user === userId;
    },
    remove: function (userId, doc) {
        // can only remove your own documents
        return doc.user === userId;
    },
    fetch: ['user']
});

campaigns.deny({
    update: function (userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
        // can't change owners
        return _.contains(fields, 'owner');
    }
});
```

and the mup.json file:

```html
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "168.235.151.xxx",
      "username": "dvterritorg", // develop user
      "password": "xxxxxx"
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      //"pem": "~/.ssh/id_rsa"


    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.36 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.36",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "dvterritorg",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": ".",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://dv.xxxxxx.it",
    //"MONGO_URL": "mongodb://dvterritorg:xxxxxx@127.0.0.1/dvterritorg",
    "METEOR_ENV": "production"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 60
}
```

I tried to deploy in meteor.com and with compose.io but the result is the same.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as expected. Mongo is a NoSQL database. Collections are made as soon as you insert data into them. Your databases have no data hence no collections. This is also the case with any mongo database such as those `meteor.com` hosting via `mup deploy` (if you used compose or a local database like in your script above).

MUP, or `meteor deploy`, do not upload your local database's content, if that is your intention. You have to do this yourself using `mongodump` and `mongorestore`: https://docs.compose.io/backups/mongodump-mongorestore.html

You can get the mongorestore & mongodump binaries from [mongodb.org](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads)

You can dump your local database (if you run meteor on port 3000 - add one) :

```
mongodump --port 3001
```

This creates `dump` folder which you can use to restore using `mongorestore` which may require more authentication details as outlined in the compose.io article above.